# Does a nested hardfail statement in an "include:" SPF entry take priority over a softfail in the parent entry?

Tags: smtp, spf

Let's say I have a SPF record that reads:

`v=spf1 include:_foo.example.com ~all`

and let's say that `_foo.example.com` has the following:

`vspf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 -all`

Does the `-all` entry in the nested spf record take priority?  Or would the `~all` entry in the parent record have priority?

Answer (score 1):

In short: `~all`, but not because of priority. An `include` can only `Pass`.

This is described in the documentation for the [`include` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include):

> In hindsight, the name "include" was poorly chosen. Only the evaluated
>   result of the referenced SPF record is used, rather than acting as if
>   the referenced SPF record was literally included in the first. For
>   example, evaluating a `-all` directive in the referenced record does
>   not terminate the overall processing and does not necessarily result
>   in an overall `Fail`. (Better names for this mechanism would have been
>   "if-pass", "on-pass", etc.)

In other words it's not a matter of priority but rather the processing order: if the `include` doesn't `Pass` (not because of just the `-all` but also anything else inside it), it can't be used as `Pass`, as it otherwise could, but it won't cause overall `Fail` either. As a result, it will fall back to the `~all` in the original SPF record.